# How make camera translate with touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How make a camera translate on touch? Its movement left or right is correct, but up and down is not.

Here is my code so far:

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
{
    Touch currentTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        this.dragOrigin = this.getWorldPoint(currentTouch.position);

    if (currentTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector3 worldDelta = getWorldPoint(currentTouch.position) - this.dragOrigin;

        Vector3 move = new Vector3 (worldDelta.x * dragSpeed, worldDelta.y * dragSpeed, 0);

        Camera.main.transform.Translate(move.x, move.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your world coordinate system, Y could be height (up/down), so you might need to use worldDelta.z instead of worldDelta.y (you would also need to adjust the parameters of the Translate call to move the camera appropriately).

Hope that helps!